# Redis as Session_Store Doesn't Work But CookieStore Does after upgrading from Rails 5.1 to 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies, session-store

Redis for session_store is no longer working after upgrading rails from 5.1 to 7 even though I've updated every possible thing I can find. Redis version = 7.2.3

Updated the Gemfile to remove redis-rails and include redis-actionpack now that it comes packaged in >= Rails5.2:

```
gem 'redis', '~> 5.0'
gem 'redis-actionpack', "~> 5.3"
```

In my config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, 
  servers: ['redis://localhost:6379/0/session'],
  key:  '_repubclub_session_development',
  expire_after: 1.days,
  signed: true,
  secure: false
```

When I run:
`redis-cli monitor` I see page requests reach Redis via output like:

```
1700062813.721011 [0 127.0.0.1:56195] "get" "2::a8fa0f1717f3b52bc7eb07bf006a569c3b9b2df87d70c93c5b2e500eea8ee53d"
1700062813.721201 [0 127.0.0.1:56195] "get" "dAmCGwLx3ebmdgLw96uWZnWO1agkR7DVtG1BzI5G8BxKoKEqmKuq+ZFzXIHL6w6dw2iERbwstVnmvrxVpDKcSEXmrDxZJs4u3zefOxz3/tr0uhtkUJlgLTtLHVEVveOo2XGfnoogMz1LkwOnKlinF4zVgRpGxqPZa3s5mxbwAQVQAQpnGqd8EHc5uYh6v0I3Evf2qXe0Dgw=--RTUjmnuEhMUDjlaz--ANyGuVkg015jrcKfYrwBNw=="
1700062813.768143 [0 127.0.0.1:56195] "setex" "2::ff56f6c452380a5887983d14c24c5d9673483a68e7ff1ee0945227e22fce9a03" "86400" "\x04\b{\aI\"\x0blocale\x06:\x06EF\"\aenI\"\x10_csrf_token\x06;\x00FI\"0-9bP3MWCLQfS_uX1BrCpQ9cDiyzEpTaRfz_uTSi7zpg\x06;\x00F"
```

Yet no flash messages are displayed and any put/post requests lead to an "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error shown below:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for ::1 at 2023-11-15 11:22:46 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"cellphone"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3845)
```

When I swap back to using Rails' cookie_store, it works again and I receive flash messages and authentication as appropriate.

Comment: Is this happening 9n development? I remember that I had a similar issue back than. Have a look at environmental/development.log. the Session Store is only configured if the file tmp/caching.txt is present. So a "touch tmp/caching.txt" might help

Comment: It's failing in production and development but I will look into that.  Thanks